# Java Socket never ending loop

Tags: java, sockets, loops, process

Hello I was doing a command system with Java. For an example: you type "date" and you see the time and date BUT then this problem came up and when I was trying to fix it, it was a never ending loop. Here's my code with a bit explanation:

```
switch(string){
case "date":
    //Give date

case "random":
    //The thing is when you type "random" it will wait on the next input from the user and store it in this variable.

    while(!string2.equals("BREAK")){
        String string2 = (String) inputdata.readObject();
        //It will process the users next information if the user NOT type "BREAK".
    }
    break;

    //The problem is that the variable "string2" must be outside the while loop BUT it NEEDS in the loop. I tried with do while loop but the same problem happend.
}
```

If I must solve this problem I must do loops in loops in loops in loops in loops....
Thanks for an answer. :D comment if you don't understand, I didnt understand my question either in the begining.

Comment: did you tried equalsIgnoreCase in compairing...Sometimes it occours due to case sensitivity

Comment: Why are you using `readObject()` to read user typed information?

Comment: why not readObject(), what should I use?

Comment: What type is `inputdata`?

Comment: is the variable I write for the input stream

Comment: why don't you break after the case "date"? What will happen if you input "date" and "string2" doesn't equal "BREAK"?

Comment: ? That is not the question....

Comment: Like what? Give always an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you declare string2 outside of the loop and then reference it inside, like this?

```
String string2;
switch(string){
case "date":
//Give date

case "random":
//The thing is when you type "random" it will wait on the next input from the user and store it     in this variable.

while(!string2.equals("BREAK")){
    string2 = (String) inputdata.readObject();
    //It will process the users next information if the user NOT type "BREAK".
}
break;

//The problem is that the variable "string2" must be outside the while loop BUT it NEEDS in the loop. I tried with do while loop but the same problem happend.
}
```